# where is the object being created in the method below?

Tags: java, object, instantiation

I know in Java everything is got to revolve around objects. But in the code below-

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
statement = con.createStatement();
result = statement.executeQuery(query);
```

where is the object being created? I can't seem to see the new keyword here.What am I missing here?

```
public String sqlQuery(String userN, String server, String database, String query) {

    try {
        String userName = "" + userN + "";
        String password = "Password1";
        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://" + server + "" + ";databaseName=" + database + "";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
        Statement statement;
        statement = con.createStatement();
        result = statement.executeQuery(query);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return userN;
}
```

Comment: There are several "objects", which one are you referring to?  The `Connection` object?  It looks like the `getConnection()` method returns that.  The `Statement` object?  `createStatement()` returns that.  The object in the `result` variable?  There's a method returning that object too...

Comment: if you think maybe 5s about it, you should know that you could encapsulate the `new ...` inside any method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> where is the object being created?

They are created inside these methods:

`DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);`

`con.createStatement();`

`statement.executeQuery(query);`

and their referencs are returned to you.

Insides these methods, or some other mehtods they called, there should be a`new` method that you have been looking for.

Comment: yes you are absolutely right! i was searching for the new key word. how ignorant of me! thank you!

Answer (score 3):

`getConnection`, `createStatement` and `executeQuery` create new instances of classes that implement `Connection`, `Statement` and `ResultSet`, respectively, and return them.

Answer (score 2):

`con` is being created inside `getConnection`

`statement` inside `createStatement`

and `result` in `executeQuery`.

It doesn't matter if you already had those objects before, when you assign them you are getting new objects

Answer (score 2):

The **Object** is created in static method `getConnection` of class `DriverManager`, and then this method return a **reference** to the created `Connection Object`.